# Limiting the number of rows in one to many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT address.addressid,
       employee.employeeid
FROM employee,
     address
WHERE address.employeeid = employee.employeeid;
```

Which produces the following output:

[image: Output]

Now I want to limit the rows saying the employees who have more than two addresses will be only displayed by the query. How do I achieve that?

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Do you want to display only employees who have more than two addresses or do you want to display only one row for every employee who has more than one address? What is the desired output?

Comment: implicit join is discouraged...

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT etc.

Comment: @TimSchmelter want to display the rows of addresses as well with employee id.Tell me both ways.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : It is postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select address.addressid,
       employee.employeeid
from employee,
     address
where address.employeeid = employee.employeeid
group by employee.employeeid
having count(address.employeeid) > 2
```